# Android Studio: Gradle suddenly can't link files and doesn't recognize module "app"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've been using Android Studio on Windows 8 with this project for a couple months, and earlier today the sidebar suddenly doesn't show any of the project files (just the Gradle Scripts). At the same time, the Gradle build also keeps failing, with dozens of errors of the form `"cannot find symbol class X"`. Finally, when I go into the "Build" menu, it only has a "make project" option but not a "make module 'app'" option, and I suspect that it is unaware of the module 'app' anymore.

This error persists when I switch to different Git branches of the same project, but not when I switch to a different project. I've tried re-importing the project (including deleting the `.iml` files and `.idea` folder beforehand), I've tried clearing out the folder and re-syncing, and I've tried reinstalling Android Studio.

I've included a screenshot below that shows some of the Gradle errors and the sidebar that doesn't contain any of the project files.

[image: included a screenshot]

Comment: Navigate to ''Run" option at top of android studio, click on "Edit Configuration", select module "app" or "no module" option.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning project by selecting `clean project` option under `Build` menu.

Also try building after deleting `builds` dir in the project.

Comment: Doing both of these, git pulling, and re-syncing Gradle seems to have fixed it. Thanks!